# Location-Based redirection and duplication in sub-directories affecting SEO

Tags: seo, redirects, subdirectory

I currently own the website `www.xyz.com`. The website has a sub-directory for each of the 3 target countries: `.../en-US/` (United States), `.../es-MX/` (Mexico), and `.../es-DO/` (Dominican Republic). I have two main questions about this setup:

Currently, the main `domain/root` (`xyz.com`) contains a blank `index.php` file, but I would like for a user to be redirected to one of the sub-directories based on their regional location. What is the best way to accomplish this? I have looked at using browser language-based redirection, but how would I know whether to direct a user to the MX or DO site if the browser language is set to spanish? Is there a way to detect a user's geographic location?

Also, the 3 websites are practically identical except they all have 3 unique color schemes and the US site is in english while the MX and DO sites are in spanish. My problem is that I believe GoogleBot is penalizing/banning my site because the spanish text on the MX and DO pages are nearly identical and are thus marked as duplicates/spam. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: If the MX and DO pages are nearly identical, then what is the purpose of having 2 distinct sites? I think we need to know a little more about the differences, or the purpose of this geographical rather than language-based segmentation.

Comment: I have them as two different sites because although the text is the same, the images are different. And in the future, the text might be changed as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Why/how are the images different? And how would the text defer? Why would the text defer in the future (why not now)?

Comment: Basically, the company will be operating in each of the locations with content tailored to each location. However, the site just launched so they're very similar.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your last question, Google does say

> Websites that provide content for different regions and in different
>   languages      sometimes create content that is the same or similar
>   but available on different URLs. This is generally not a problem as
>   long as the content is for different users in different countries.
>   While we strongly recommend that you provide unique content for each
>   different group of users, we understand that this may not always be
>   possible. 
>   http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192

So in this case you need to implement 'rel-alternate-hreflang' to tell Google that you have similar content in the same language but it's for a different country.

[rel-alternate-hreflang](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077)

Quick example:

So as you have several alternate URLs targeted at users with the same language but in different locales, you have specific URLs for Spanish speakers in Mexico (es-mx), Dominican Republic (es-do), but want English speakers from The United States to see your US English (en-us) page, and for your auto-redirecting homepage, you should add an annotation for the hreflang value "x-default" as well. In this case you can annotate this cluster of pages using a Sitemap file or using HTML link tags like this:

```
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://www.xyz.com/es-DO/” hreflang=”es-do” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://www.xyz.com/es-MX/” hreflang=”es-mx” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://www.xyz.com/en-US/” hreflang=”en-us” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://www.xyz.com/” hreflang=”x-default” />
```